# PHP not parsing variable as html

Tags: php

I am using some JS and PHP API to display some content on webpage. And api has few javascripts path like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="www.example.com/?data='key'" data-id="someid">
```

that are stored in my database and updating after few times and I have to include these scripts on my webpage to display the content. The problem is I am getting the script in PHP variable and try to include the script like :

```
$script = $row->script; //complete script path with tag
if(isset($_REQUEST['page1'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['page1'])){
    echo $script;
}
```

But it is not working, `$script` is not parsing the real script, it is showing the complete script path (tag) as it is saved in the database.

Comment: What is value of `$row->script` ?

Comment: `$row->script` complete script path with tags coming from database

Comment: `"it is showing the complete script path (tag) as it is saved in the database"` - Well, what else would it be doing?  If that value is coming from the database, and you are echo-ing that value to the page, wouldn't you expect to see what's in the database?

Comment: @David, showing like `<script type="text/javascript" src="www.example.com/?data='key'" data-id="someid">` and Not parsing the this line showing as it is.

Comment: @Nishant: Define "parsing".  Because that (mostly) looks like valid HTML to me.

Comment: @David, now its working fine I have used `html_entity_decode()` as #Sanchit mentioned bellow. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse `$script` as HTML you have to use php predefined function:

`html_entity_decode($string)`

Use your code like:

`$script = $row->script; //complete script path with tag`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['page1'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['page1'])){
    echo html_entity_decode($script);
}
```

For more detail [HTML ENTITY DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Thankyou for quick responce. Now its working fine thanks :). Thanks again